# Rails 4 custom controller action error - "Couldn't find 'model' without an ID"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add a custom create action for my Book model, but i keep ending up with a "Couldn't find Book without an ID".

routes.rb:

```
Books::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :books

  resources :books do
    collection do
      post 'create_new_record', :action => :create_new_record
    end
  end 

  match 'create_new_record' => 'books#create_new_record', via: [:post]
```

The relevant controller action:

```
  def create_new_record
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.save
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'New book record created.' }
      end
    end
  end
```

And my form (in new.html.erb). I'm looping through results that i get from goodreads.com.

```
<% @book_search.results.work.each do |stuff| %>

    <%= form_for(@book, :url => create_new_record_books_path) do |f| %>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :author %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :author, :value => stuff.best_book.author.name %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :title %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :title, :value => stuff.best_book.title %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :isbn %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :isbn, :value => stuff.best_book.isbn %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :image %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :image, :value => stuff.best_book.image_url %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :bookid %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :bookid, :value => stuff.best_book.id %>
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
    <hr>
<% end %>
```

The error i get when submitting the form is:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BooksController#create_new_record

on the callback

```
def set_book
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
end
```

I'm pretty much stumped now, my understanding is that it doesn't even reach the action, but instead looks for a book id that doesn't exist?

Thank you!

Comment: There are missing calls: where is called set_book?

Comment: Can you please paste your params here.?

Comment: Are you calling `set_book` via a `before_filter`? Could you share with us the `Books` controller code?

Comment: where is your callback? is it either controller before filter or model callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use before_filter so you don't pass an id to create action. Call your before filter the following way:

```
before_filter :set_book, except: [:index, :new, :create]
```

If you use model callback, params is unavailable in the model so pass the id some other way, for example via attr_accessor.

Comment: I feel like a total idiot now, this was it! I had the set before_action to the create_new_record action, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use `@book = Book.where(id: params[:id]).first`